# Have NeoVim confirm before closing when terminals are open

Tags: neovim, terminal

When we type `:qa` or `:wqa`, neovim quits/save-and-quits all buffers. This also closes any terminal buffers that are open, even if there are pending jobs running. Those jobs just get killed!

Is there a way to have neovim ask for a confirmation when a terminal window is open (like trying to do a `:qa` when there are edited buffers). This way the running jobs aren't killed, when I accidently type `:qa` to quit vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed [this script](https://gist.github.com/ds26gte/034b9ac9edeaf86d0ff5c73f97dd530b). It does the job, but the presented message is a general one. That may be confusing